# Check if the bilinear form given in the standard basis gives some dot product to $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, bilinear-form

> Check if the bilinear form given in the standard basis by $$\begin{bmatrix}
>      1 &4 &0\\
>      4 &4 &0\\
>      0 &0 &2
> \end{bmatrix}$$ gives some dot product to $\mathbb R^3$.

I need confirmation that my solution is correct:

One of the conditions for the dot product is non-negative definiteness. Thus, for a given bilinear form to give some dot product, the given matrix must be non-negative definite, which is equivalent to all eigenvalues of the matrix being non-negative. Let's check:
$$\left| \begin{matrix}
     1-\lambda &4 &0\\
     4 &4-\lambda &0\\
     0 &0 &2-\lambda
\end{matrix} \right|=(1-\lambda)(4-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-16(2-\lambda)$$ $$=(2-\lambda)(4-\lambda -4\lambda +\lambda^2 -16)=(2-\lambda)(\lambda ^2 -5\lambda -12)$$
$$\lambda_1=2, \lambda_2=\frac{\sqrt{73}+5}{2}, \lambda_3\frac{-\sqrt{73}+5}{2}$$
$\lambda_3<0$, so the matrix is not non-negative definite, i.e. the form cannot specify an dot product, and there is no need to check the rest of the product conditions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info : "This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and you have specific concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

Comment: That said, your solution is correct. A shorter one would be: $\begin{vmatrix}
     1 &4 &0\\
     4 &4 &0\\
     0 &0 &2
\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}
     1 &4 \\
     4 &4 
\end{vmatrix}<0.$

Comment: You can also look at the leading $2\times 2$ block and eyeball/linearize the result:  Perron theory tells you its maximal eigenvalue is $\gt 5$ (minimum row sum which is strictly less than maximum row sum) but the trace is $5$ so there is a negative eigenvalue as well.

Comment: Perron theory is really overkill here. As previously noticed, the "leading $2\times 2$ block" has a determinant $\lambda\mu=-12<0,$ where $\lambda,\mu$ are its eigenvalues.

Comment: Not that it matters here, but dot products are supposed to have the property that $v \cdot v = 0$ only when $v = 0$. So for $w^*Av$ to be a dot product, $A$ needs to be positive definite, not just non-negative definite.